# Hardhat Console getBalance() does NOT show custom Token

Tags: erc-20, hardhat, testing

Here is my contract:

```
    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) ERC20(_name, _symbol) { }

    function giveMePaisa() public {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10 * 10 ** 18);
    }
}
```

From Hardhat console testing ... I am able to successfully transfer my custom Tokens to test accounts:

> await meraToken.connect(addr2).giveMePaisa();

But, when I try to see my custom tokens ...

> await ethers.provider.getBalance(addr2.address);

I see ( which I assume are Ethers ) :

> BigNumber { value: "9999999976573474278440" }

**How can I see my custom tokens from Hardhat console ?**

Comment: You have to query the token contract's `balanceOf` function.

Comment: @deep I recommend reading the [ERC20 Token Standard](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ethers.provider.getBalance(addr2.address);

Will fetch you the Ethereum balance of the addr2.address, what you need to do is call `balanceOf` on the meraToken contract with addr2.address as parameter.

> await meraToken.balanceOf(addr2.address);

Hope that helps